# Refactoring code in using specification pattern for business rules

Tags: c#, refactoring, cqrs, specifications

I want to use `Specification` pattern to apply business rules in my `N-Layerd DDD` application.
I used `CQRS` pattern in my `Application Layer` also.
So I defined following `Interface` in my `Domain`:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> Predicate { get; }
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity);
}
```

and also some `Specification`s that implement above interface such as `BigOrderSpecification : ISpecification<Order>` and `SpecialOrderSpecification:ISpecification<Order>`.

I used following handler to process my orders:

```
public class OrderProcessCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<Order>
{
    OrderCommand _command;
    public OrderProcessCommandHandler(OrderCommand command) 
    {
       _command = command;
    }
    public Handle()
    {
        var bigOrderSpec = new BigOrderSpecification();
        var specialOrderSpec = new SpecialOrderSpecification();
        var spec = bigOrderSpec.And(specialOrderSpec);
        if (spec.IsSatisfiedBy(_commnand.Order))
           // do some things
        else
            throw new BusinessException("Some business rules violated.") 
    }      
}
```

I think the `Handle()` method of `OrderProcessCommandHandler`, violates

- The `Tell don't ask` principle, because he ask `BR` satisfaction result from `Order` and then decides to do somethings.
- The `Open/Close` principle, because if I want to add another specification, I have to change my `CommandHandler`.

  How could I refactor my code to prevent this violations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not say that it violates that principles

1. **[Tell don't ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) principle.**

   Your code follows this principle since you tell `Handle()` and your "logic" and "data" are placed in one single method.

   It can be violated if your `do some things` logic tells something to `SpecialOrderSpecification`.
2. **Open/Close principle**

   Your code follows this principle since you should not change `ICommandHandler<T>` interface if you want to add another one specification.

   It can be violated if adding another one specification requires changing of `ICommandHandler<T>` interface.

In order to follow **Dependency Inversion principle** I suggest you inject all your specifications (e.g. `BigOrderSpecification`, `SpecialOrderSpecification`) via constructor.

Comment: +1. And, if you inject your dependencies (i.e. the spec) you could compose the spec outside the handler and a change in spec composition wouldn't affect the handler class at all.